# Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.0". (Nginx/Ubuntu)

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

When adding new dependencies to my composer, everything works perfectly fine locally. However, when pushing it to a Ubuntu (20.04) server, I got the following error.

> Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies
> require a PHP version ">= 8.0.0".

But I already updated my server version of php to 8.0.12 as well, or at least when I look for the version of php in the Ubuntu server, I find

```
> # php -v PHP 8.0.12 (cli) (built: Oct 22 2021 12:34:48) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) The PHP Group Zend Engine v4.0.12, Copyright (c) Zend
> Technologies
>     with Zend OPcache v8.0.12, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Delving deeper into it, I find in the error log of Nginx the following statement:

```
Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.0". You are running 7.4.3. in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24" while reading response header from upstream, client: ........, server: _, request: "GET /login HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:"
```

which gives a clear reference to 'php7.4-fpm.sock', so no php8. This is where it gets weird for me, as I have changed the reference in the etc/nginx/sites-available/default file, as shown:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        # fastcgi_index index.php;
        # fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        # fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        # include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

So somehow it still references to the php version 7.4. I've tried removing the php7.4-fpm files with sudo apt-get autoremove as I got a message saying they were not in use anymore, but then I got a 502 bad gateway error with the following

```
connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed
```

Would really like some help with this as I'm stuck with this for a while now.

*Note: I've also tried the suggestion of

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

but that resulted in a 501 internal error.

** Added the complete code of the sites-available configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _ DOMAIN www.DOMAIN;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        # fastcgi_index index.php;
        # fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        # fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        # include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

**FIX**
I finally found a fix after stumbling upon the following tutorial

https://www.vultr.com/docs/upgrade-php-7-4-to-php-8-0-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-nginx

I don't exactly know what it does, but it's definitely Step 4 of the configuration that did it, as I've never seen those steps in other tutorials. It's probably the substituting of the socket that did it, but it still seems weird to me as it was not as if I didn't have the new socket.

Comment: Did you restart your nginx server? It may be using the old config.

Comment: I did, that didn't help either unfortunately.

Comment: It really seems like an nginx problem. The fact that you've removed the php files causes a 502 seems like it is nginx that is pointing to the wrong php version

Comment: That's what I think as well, but I have no clue how to make it point to the right version, apart from changing the sites-available/default file, which I already did.

Comment: Do you have other configs in `sites-available`?

Comment: I have added the complete code of the default file in sites-available.

Answer (score -2):

Composer must be using PHP 7.4. My suggestion would be to download a fresh copy of composer here:

https://getcomposer.org/download/

And executing composer like this:

```
php composer.phar install
```

Since you know `php -v` version is 8.0.12

Comment: Composer isn't php specific...